# Remove Trailing Zeros when AccountNo is greater than 15 digits or X digits

Tags: java, string

I am really trying to make this work in Java, but still unable to fix it. My Account range varies from 15 digits to 19 digits.

Ex-1:

```
String accountNo = "1111101111111100000";
String accountNo1= "11111011111111";
```

I need to remove all the **trailing zeros** and compare if **accountNo=11111011111111** and **accountNo1=11111011111111**, both are same, then mark it as true.

I used below code, but does not help where Account Number actually contains 0 at the end. Sometime, I know if AccountNo is of 15 digits, then check updatedAcc all characters/digits are present in the account and if matches then consider true?

The comparison mostly I wants to do List vs List

```
String account = "1111101111111100000"; //19 digits
String updatedAcc ="11111011111111";
String value = account.replaceAll("0+$", "");
```

Ex2: In this case, I don't want to remove all zero. Last zero should be keep as is. I hope you get the question now.

```
String account = "1111101111111000000"; //19 digits
String updatedAcc ="11111011111110";
String value = account.replaceAll("0+$", "");
```

Comment: why down voted this?

Comment: Please see the edit Ex-2

Comment: So you want to remove trailing zeros only when the length is equal to 15?

Comment: Length Could be dyanamic 15-19, if its 16 digits, then I need to remove 3 zeros, if its 17 digits, then remove 2 zeros and so on. "updatedAcc" length is the final length, based on that I have to take decision

Comment: After getting both as String, another approach would be to pad with trailing 0 up to the max length, then compare.

Comment: @ Andrew S - I am looking to de-pad and compare. Could you post code which should be dynamic ?

Comment: Ex2 should end with 00 not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an ideal solution, but this was the best I could come up with :

```
    if (accountNo.length() > 15) {
        if (accountNo.substring(16, accountNo.length()).matches("000")) {
            accountNo = accountNo.substring(1, 16);
        } else if (accountNo.substring(17, accountNo.length()).matches("00")) {
            accountNo = accountNo.substring(1, 17);
        } else if (accountNo.substring(18, accountNo.length()).matches("0")) {
            accountNo = accountNo.substring(1, 18);
        }
    }
```